# Compilation fails with C++ structures members initialization

Tags: c++, compilation, initialization

I compile and link my code on Ubuntu 16.04 with GCC 5.4.0.

In my large project there is an interface file, that describes the structures in program interface. Many classes include that file and declare members from the interface structures.

At first, all the interface structures were without members initialization. For example:

```
Interface.hpp

struct Vertex {
  double lon;
  double lat;
  int alt;
}

struct Debug{
  int debugBuffer[5][3];
}
```

and a compilation of some specific class file resulted in an object file about 553KB size.
My compilation line is:

```
**release**
g++ -std=c++1y -I<all include folder> -m64 -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-reorder -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -fPIC myfile.cpp

**debug**
g++ -std=c++1y -I<all include folder> -m64 -c -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-reorder -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O0 -g3 -fPIC myfile.cpp
```

Afterwards, I've changed all the structure to be with initialized members, like that:

```
Interface.hpp

struct Vertex {
  double lon = {33.0};
  double lat = {35.3};
  int alt = {0};
}

struct Debug{
  int debugBuffer[5][3] = {{0}};
}
```

After that change, the object *myfyle.o* compiles to debug 3 time longer and takes 6.5MB in size. In release it won't compile at all - no errors, just stucks after a couple of seconds. The process runs, but it's like it enters an endless loop - just no output in the terminal.

And now the questions:

1. I don't understand why the initialization increases the size so much and why does the compilation takes longer.
2. Why does the compilation of a release stuck?
3. What do I do wrong? I wan't to use the initialization to interface default values, so how do I do that to avoid such problems?

Thanks.

*P.S.* I can't publish the real code, since it's in out intranet and it's sensitive.

Comment: What is the `-std=c++1+` compiler option?  I've not seen that.

Comment: g++ -std=c++1+: error, unrecognized command-line option

Comment: please provide a [mre], your code doesn't compile and your compiler command line is invalid

Comment: -std=c++1y
setting the dialect to C++14 and later

Comment: The two versions do different things.  Do you have a lot of `Vertex` or `Debug` objects in your headers or sources?  The original code won't have any constructor/initializer code for them, while the new version adds this extra code that the compiler has to deal with.

Comment: Yes, as I said, my project is large, it has a lot of classes that widely use the interface structures. I haven't checked, but I don't think that if I initialize all members in those classes C'tors instead, it would result in freezing the release compilation and enlarge the debug object in 12 times.